# Nan from maths equation

Tags: java, double, nan

Hi I have the following equation in a piece of java code:

```
double z = 0.002378 * (Math.pow((1 - (Math.pow(6.875, -6) * y)), 4.2561));
```

when I set y to be very large values, i.e `200000` I get `Nan` (Not a number) It's working okay at slightly lower values, `130000`

Can anyone tell me why that is?

Additionally I've tried to port the above code from an original BASIC program:

```
.002378*(1-(6.875*10^-6*ALT))^4.2561
```

I may have done it wrong? The order of operations isn't very explicit in the BASIC code

Thanks

Comment: you know that `^` is logical XOR, and not the power function? You're probably looking for the `Math.pow()` method.

Comment: That code won't even slightly compile.  Please post your real code.

Comment: This isnt java code, I have written the equation using standard maths notation

Comment: Added the actual code

Comment: My bad :( first one is wrong

Comment: Ok, you should check the rules for `Math.pow` (and learn what circumstances cause it to return `NaN`): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the Javadoc for `Math.pow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) explains:

> If the first argument is finite and less than zero [… and] the second argument is finite and not an integer, then the result is NaN.

So whenever your `y` is great enough that `1 - (Math.pow(6.875, -6) * y` is negative, you'll get NaN.

(This makes sense when you consider the underlying math. A negative number to a non-integer power is not a real number, and `double` has no way to represent complex numbers.)

---

**Edited for updated question:**

Your Basic code has `6.875*10^-6` (meaning 6.875 × 10<sup>−6</sup>), but your Java code has `Math.pow(6.875, -6)` (meaning 6.875<sup>−6</sup>), which is a somewhat greater value, so your Java code triggers this problem for somewhat smaller values of `y`. This may be why you're seeing this problem now. To match the Basic code, you should change `Math.pow(6.875, -6)` to `6.875e-6`.

Comment: It seems to have a max limit of around 140000, but I guess thats a limit of the equation and no longer a problem with my implementation. Hopefully

Answer (score 0):

Raising a negative number to a non-integer power results in an imaginary number in complex number mathematics, a NaN in Java arithmetic. If you really need to do that calculation, you need a complex number package. However, it is more likely that there is an error in your equation or you are trying to use it outside its range of validity.

Answer (score 0):

Negtive number with real number power may get NAN